# Analytic Integration, or, closed-form expression for an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, closed-form

I have been trying to integrate this function analytically for quite some time. I have already used Taylor series expansion, and it is not helpful. So, I want to integrate f = $\cos{(K_4 + K_5 x + \pi K_6 + K_2 \tan^{-1}{(K_1 \tan{\frac{x}{2}})}-\frac{K_3 \tan{\frac{x}{2}}}{1+K_1^2 tan^2{\frac{x}{2}}})}$ over $0$ to $2\pi$ where the variable of integration is x, and the parameters $K_1,K_2,K_3,K_4,K_5,K_6$ are some constants. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you. Additional note: I do not want to integrate it numerically; in fact, I want to compare the analytical result with numerical result as a way of verification.

Comment: I would be very surprised if this had a closed form.

Comment: May I ask where is this integral helping you?

Comment: Where is the question from? A book? Online site? Research paper?